# how to serialize "std::string" using tpl

Tags: c++, c, serialization, stdstring

```
    std::string content = readFile();
char *carray = const_cast<char*>(content.c_str());
tpl_node *tn = tpl_map("s", carray);
tpl_pack(tn, 0);
tpl_dump(tn, TPL_FILE, "player.dat");
tpl_free(tn);
```

i want serialize std::string to tpl_map("s", ...), but it doesn't work.
throw a run-time exception in

> HelloCppWin32.exe!tpl_pack(tpl_node * r, int i) Line 1864   C

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the pointer to the char array, not the char array. Notice the extra * in the table of supported format characters copied from the [official TPL page](https://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/userguide.html#format):

```
Type    Description     Required argument type
s       string          char**
```

In your case, that would be:

tpl_node *tn = tpl_map("s", **&** carray);